# Why Lord Parashurama, incarnation of Lord Vishnu, worship Lord Shiva?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, parashurama

Parashurama is an incarnation of Lord Vishnu that we all know, but why he, being an incarnation of Lord Vishnu, worship Lord Shiva?

Comment: Not only Parashurama, Lord Rama and Lord Krishna too worshiped Lord Shiva. And sometimes Lord Shiva or his incarnations is shown worshiping Lord Vishnu or his incarnations. They all have different powers and unlike humans, they don't think themselves bigger than the other God.

Comment: @Aby And in the Mahabharata, Shiva says Vishnu worships those who worship Vishnu, as I discuss here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7507/36

Comment: Aby is correct. Krishna himself workshipped Shiva and gave us the Shiva sahasranama. Rama established the rameswara linga on his way to lanka before battle with Ravana.