# Why is Ramayana known as Sharanagati Grantham?

Tags: scripture, ramayana, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

In [SriVaishnavism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2835/489) [Ramayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramayana) finds a special place in hearts of Bhagwatas(Sri Vaishanvas) and it is known as [Sharanagati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saranagati) Grantham.

What is the specific reason to call it Sharanagati Grantham.

Note: I already know the abstract reason i.e. because every Kanda of Ramayana has Sharanagati Involved, I need elaborate answer.

Comment: As you said, the reason that Sri Vaishnavas call the Valmiki Ramayana the "Sharanagati Shastram" is because every Kanda involves Sharanagati.  In the Bala Kanda, the gods seek refuge in Vishnu to defeat Ravana.  In the Ayodhya Kanda, Bharata falls at Rama's feet and asks him to come back and rule Ayodhya.  In the Aranya Kanda, the Rishis of the forest seek refuge in Rama to defeat the Rakshasas.  In the Kishkindha Kanda, Sugrive seeks refuge in Rama to defeat Vali.  In the Sundara Kanda, Sita tells Ravana to surrender to Rama.  And in the Yuddha Kanda, Vibhushana surrenders to Rama.

Comment: For more details, see Sri Vaishnava commentaries on the Valmiki Ramayana.  By the way, Ramanujacharya used to go to Tirupati to learn Sharanagati Shastram from his uncle Thirumalai Nambi.  Thirumalai Nambi was one of the shishyas of Yamunacharya.

Comment: @Keshav And in Uttara? Who surrenders in that?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I agree now if you put every kanda details(sharnagati related) and post an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @Tezz No, its like surrendering to your own feet(don't assume biological importance of legs). Why would any sane person surrender to his aashrita? We are not even capable of becoming dust of his lotus feet, why and how would he take refuge in us. Also remember we are limited and he is infinite, and logically infinite entity cannot take refuge in limited entity

Comment: @Yogi It is the compassion of Lord see [this question](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7507/what-does-it-mean-to-say-that-vishnu-worships-those-who-worship-him) and answer given there and also comments in the answer.

Comment: @Tezz Bhakti Yoga involves Karma + Jnana which is nearly impossible in kaliyuga so bhaktas in kaliyuga are nearly 0, and thinking like that generates certain degree of unavoidable ahamkara so it can be a trick(test) of Bhagwan. Btw If one needs to be a great Bhagwata/Bhakta he needs to understand BG 12 (bhaktiyoga chapter) and act accordingly which is very very difficult like remaining calm in sukha and dukkha.

Comment: Sri Ramayana provides us with knowledge of how to perform prapatti, but the attitude and practices after prapatti has been performed.

Comment: @M_Raghavan You mean procedure of Samashrayanam and Bharasamarpanam is available in Ramayana?

Comment: @Yogi, can you understand Tamil ? There is an upanyasam by Karunakarachariar swami on Ramayanathil Sharanagathi - it's an up & down of accepted and rejected surrenders

Comment: @ram I don't understand tamil, but I can get some help.